# pycharm flask project is not supported

Tags: python, flask, pycharm, jinja2

Getting some strange error on Pycharm version 3.0.2 under windows 8.1.  I tried 3.3.2 and 3.3.3 python version, but same.
(I have added python and python\script to environment path. no result)

Flask is not supported for the selected interpreter

[image]

Comment: It just means that the *IDE* doesn't support developing Flask projects under Python 3.3. Flask supports 3.3 just fine, of course.

Comment: no, on another PC it works fine and on mac too

Comment: it is installed on interpreter, it is global interpreter....

Answer (score 2):

This was a known problem but is now resolved. It was reported to JetBrains [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-10535).